# How to restrict login view after user logged in?

Tags: python, django

I want to open my login view only to non logged in users. means once user is logged in, he/she can not access login view by hitting /login/ url manually.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check `request.user.is_authenticated`.

Comment: @PauloScardine I am talking about restricting a "view" function by some decorator.

Comment: Any reason to not redirect the logged user to their home page rather than restricting access to login url?

Comment: Redirecting the user to the logout URL makes sense as well, because if he is hitting the login page he may really want to login as a different user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@user_passes_test`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def user_is_not_logged_in(user):
    return not user.is_authenticated()

@user_passes_test(user_is_not_logged_in)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

You can use `@user_passes_test(user_is_not_logged_in, login_url='/')` to redirect to another URL and avoid server errors.

Comment: this is working. but when user is hitting /login/ url manually after login then server is not responding. can you please suggest some method to fix this.

Comment: `@user_passes_test(user_is_not_logged_in, login_url='/')` you can use this to redirect to another url and not getting server problems.

Answer (score 2):

Just import the the LoginView and pass - `redirect_authenticated_user=True`
every thing will be completed in urls.py

So. the urls.py is-

```
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True),
          name='login'),

]
```

and that's it. Argument in LoginView will take care of your problem by redirecting logged in user. In [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)  you can read it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `anon_required` decorator (untested):

```
def anon_required(view_func):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks that the user is NOT logged in.
    """
    def decorated(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise HttpResponseBadRequest("Get out, you are authenticated.")
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

You can do anything instead of returning HTTP 400, like redirecting the user to his profile (or to the logout URL, perhaps he want to login as a different user).

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for User Login View in Django Urls file with custom Html file for Login Page
It will redirect login page on home page if user already login else Login Page will open with form to get input from you

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView


urlpatterns = [

    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='common/login.html',redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),,

]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using class based login system, just import the the LoginView and add - redirect_authenticated_user=True in urls.py

like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html', 
redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login')
```

and it will automatically be redirected to home/index page.